# Are nested closures a good thing?

Tags: swift-language, closures

I've been doing Swift development for a while now with Firebase, and I find myself making a lot of code like this:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("an error occurred while signing in!! \(error)")
        return
    }

    print("user is signed in with facebook!")

    FacebookHelper.getProfileInfo(completion: { (name, pictureUrl) in
        FirebaseHelper.setUser(user: user!, name: name, profileUrl: pictureUrl, completion: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "facebookLoggedInSegue", sender: nil)
        })
    })
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this? It can just get confusing when I've got stuff like that nested in `observe` functions.

Comment: `(user, error)` is a code smell. You're using a `tuple` where an `enum` would be more appropriate. It can model two invalid cases (`(nil, nil`)` and `(user, error)`), when only two are valid (`(user, nil)` and `(nil, error)`). Though I suspect that's probably some third party library API.

Comment: @Alexander: "Code smell" is an expression used to dehumanize whoever you are attacking. Don't use it.

Comment: @gnasher729 No, it's not. It's a potential code quality issue, and if the mere insinuation that your code could use improvement is all it takes to trigger you, then I pity your colleagues.

Comment: @Alexander you're disparaging OP because of *Google's* Firebase framework and their code?! This form of closures is pervasive through Apple's frameworks and, it seems, Google's Firebase framework. It's a fair bet that other third-party frameworks from the likes of Facebook, et al would also follow Apple's lead on this. So, what would you have OP do?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva I don't know much about firebase, so I don't know if these API's are OP's or not. Hence why I said "Though I suspect that's probably some third party library API." If this API was indeed OP's, then I would advise him to change it to use `Result<User, Error>` as a parameter, instead. `Result` is so pervasive and useful, that it got added to the standard library in Swift 5.

Comment: He's using Firebase. The `Auth.auth().signIn` method is provided by them, so how should he change anything? It's not his API.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to *have* nested functions is a good thing, but obviously any code that is confusing is not a good thing. This kind of code is ubiquitous in the context of asynchronous programming of which your code appears to be an example.

Promises can make it a bit less fugly, but they don't completely solve the problem.

There are two solutions to this. Use threads or use continuations.

It's easy to adapt an asynchronous API to a blocking one using threads and just about any kind of synchronization construct.  This is what [AwaitKit](https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit) does. Basically, you just trigger an asynchronous event, and in the completion callback have it signal a semaphore, while you wait on the semaphore in the original thread. [E.g. in AwaitKit](https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit/blob/cd5a8cae34606d5d160ee5e35a8ad84c851aee76/Sources/DispatchQueue%2BAwait.swift#L54).

First-class [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) can also be used to solve this problem. You capture the current continuation and pass that as the callback to the asynchronous operation then abandon the current flow of control, e.g. by returning. With just a bit of wrapping, you can make an asynchronous API look and feel like a blocking API with this approach. Few languages support first-class continuations, though. To model them, you can use continuation-passing style (or monadic style for a bit more control), and indeed, that is exactly what these "nested callbacks" are doing.

The `async`/`await` syntax popularized by C# was created to solve this problem. Conceptually (but not actually) it performs a local continuation-passing style transform, and then from there it's easy to make an asynchronous API look like a blocking one. (The actual transformation is much more grotty but efficient in the context of C# which doesn't handle nested functions that efficiently.) This is a fairly good solution, but Swift doesn't currently support such syntax.

[This blog post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/comparative-asynchronous-programming/) which I haven't read completely seems to detail some of the current options in the Swift ecosystem as well as explaining some of the limitations. C# didn't add `async`/`await` to the language and compiler for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) -> User? {
    var user: User? = nil
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
      Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (firUser, error) in
        if let firUser = firUser {
          user = User(id: firUser.uid, email: firUser.email, nickname: firUser.displayName)
        }
        semaphore.signal()
      }
      _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    }
    return user
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
if let user = self.authService.signIn(email: request.email, password: request.password) {
    print(user)
  }
```

Comment: Better: use a promise library that encapsulates this for you.

Comment: Great idea. Details?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva You have quite a few options for async handling like this: PromiseKit, RxSwift, ReactiveCocoa and Apple's new Combine framework. I recommend RxSwift myself

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite normal code. Straightforward, easy to understand. Once you get used to it. You can take advantage of the simplified syntax if the last parameter of a function is a closure, like this:

```
FacebookHelper.getProfileInfo() { (name, pictureUrl) in
    FirebaseHelper.setUser(user: user!, name: name, profileUrl: pictureUrl) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "facebookLoggedInSegue", sender: nil)
    }
}
```